# How do i compare boolean values assigned to #define in C++

Tags: c++, preprocessor-directive

I have to add logging to a particular module which should allow me to enable and disable the logging when required. I added a couple of #defines to do this. The code is given below

```
#define PAINT_LOG_ENABLED   true

#if PAINT_LOG_ENABLED == true

    #define PAINT_LOG_EXTENSIVELY   true

    #if PAINT_LOG_EXTENSIVELY == true
        #define PAINT_LOG_FILE_NAME     TEXT("paint-log-ex.log")
    #else
        #define PAINT_LOG_FILE_NAME     TEXT("paint-log.log")
    #endif

#endif
```

But this throws me an error saying 
fatal error C1017: invalid integer constant expression

The above code works when i use 1 and 0 instead of true and false.
Please help.

Comment: Seems to work - http://ideone.com/pF6t5a how are you using the macros?

Answer (score 2):

The c++ preprocessor can test for the existence of defined values. You don't need to use `true`. Instead of

```
 #define PAINT_LOG_ENABLED   true

 #if PAINT_LOG_ENABLED == true
```

you can simply write

```
 #define PAINT_LOG_ENABLED

 #if PAINT_LOG_ENABLED
```

Answer (score 0):

gcc compiles it. I am guessing that it's probably related to MSVC preprocessor.

However, I would advice against using defines if possible and in this case you could easily
avoid using c preprocessor by writing something like:

```
const bool PAINT_LOG_ENABLED = true;
const bool PAINT_LOG_EXTENSIVELY = PAINT_LOG_ENABLED;
const char* PAINT_LOG_FILE_NAME = PAINT_LOG_EXTENSIVELY ? "paint-log-ex.log" : "paint-log.log";
```

Comment: Note that modern compilers will eliminate if's (and their content) if it knows the result of the if.